# Unable to access files and website with IP address

Tags: php, codeigniter, webserver

I have my site hosted on GoDaddy and working on an application which is developed in Code-igniter Php. In my application I am using a library Grocery Crud. But when ever it access url related to the assets files and other files it calls them by IP address. As far as it was on local server it was running fine but as soon as I deployed it up it came up with the problem.
I know as the particular IP address is shared among many sites so that's why particular problem is occurring. but how to solve this problem is it what or something need to be configured in code igniter or some where else?

Comment: Look for a way to configure Grocery Crud to use a hostname rather than an IP address. If your hosting provider relies on name-based virtual hosting, this is likely your only option. Using hostnames instead of hardcoded IP addresses is a best practice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are in a shared hosting environment:

> I know as the particular IP address is shared among many sites

That's why you cannot access your site with its IP address. It's not possible. Period.

There's nothing to configure in Codeigniter, because it's the configuration of the HTTP server. HTTP server handles requests.

When you type a url in your browser, it will resolve the corresponding IP address. Then it will request the IP address, saying what hostname you are trying to reach. Based on these information, HTTP server will be able to handle your request and send it to the appropriate website.

When you type an IP address in your browser, HTTP server will not know what hostname you want to reach. Depending on the configuration, it will do what it has to, but probably not send the request to your site: in shared hosting environment, there is no reason for hoster to send request to a specific website it hosts. It will most probably display a 404, 403 or redirect to their homepage.

Many hosting providers assign a temporary hostname for your website, generally as a subdomain of theirs. You should temporarily use this hostname for your website.

To configure this hostname, open `application/config/config.php` and set the `base_url` parameter.

You can load different configuration files depending on your environment (for example: development, staging, production). See [Handling multiple environments](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html#handling-multiple-environments) in CI documentation.